# How we can import conditional css file for particular html page in Angular 4 application?

Tags: angular

How we can import conditional css file for particular html page in Angular 4 application?

For example:

I have two css: `A.css` and `B.css`. 

I want to apply css `A.css` to `foo.component.html` page and css `B.css` to `bar.component.html` page.

So, how can I achieve this different styling?

It should be compatible for IE also.

Comment: Hi! I found [an article](https://shekhargulati.com/2018/01/16/dynamically-loading-css-in-angular-5-application/) and [a code sample](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4202#issuecomment-339420111) that may be useful for you! They're both about changing css dynamically on the whole app.

Comment: If you want to use a custom css for each component instead, you can achieve that with a component specific css that you'll link inside `styleUrls` (e.g.:`styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']`) inside `@Component` decorator. Here you can override style for tags in THAT specific component. For example, if you style the `div` tag in the main css to have red backgound by default, if you set it in the component css to have blue background it will be red everywhere but not in that component, where it will be blue. Notice that `styleUrls` is an array so you can link more css files

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response. It is helpful to me. @Deadpool

Comment: You're welcome! I'll write it as an answer! Feel free to accept it if my suggestion helped you in a relevant way :)

Answer (score 0):

**CHANGING CSS IN THE WHOLE APP**

If you want to change CSS dynamically in the whole app, I found [an article](https://shekhargulati.com/2018/01/16/dynamically-loading-css-in-angular-5-application/) and [a code sample](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4202#issuecomment-339420111) that may be useful for you.

 They're both about changing css dynamically on the whole app.

**OVERRIDING CSS PROPERTIES JUST IN A SPECIFIC COMPONENT**

If you want to use a custom css for each component instead, you can achieve that with a component specific css that you'll link inside `styleUrls` (e.g.:`styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']`) inside `@Component` decorator:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mycomponent',
  templateUrl: './mycomponent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mycomponent.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent //...
```

In that css file you can override style, and the style will apply just in THAT specific component.

For example, if you style the `div` tag in the main css to have red backgound by default, if you set it in the component css to have blue background it will be red everywhere but not in that component, where it will be blue.

Notice that `styleUrls` is an array so you can link more css files, so you can have also shared css properties between more components.

For more, here you can find the [Official Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles) about it